# Requirements in Engel's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I have learned the statement of [Engel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel%27s_theorem). The condition on $L$ is that it must be finite dimensional.

Now I can ask the question: Why? Can someone give me an example of an infinite dimensional $L$, where Engel's theorem does not apply?

Comment: Let $L_k$ be a finite-dimensional, nilpotent Lie-algrebra with nilpotency index $\geq k$ (i.e. the $k$-th term of the lower central series is zero but the $k-1$-th is not). Then $L=\bigoplus_{k}L_k$ is not nilpotent and is the counter-example you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! So for example i start with a Lie algebra $C_0=L$ und then consider the central series $C_i=[L,C_0]$. But why does this work?

Comment: What happens is that the $k-1$-th term of the lower central series of $L_k$ is nonzero, so the   $k-1$-th term of the lower central series of $L$ is nonzero also (since $L_k\subseteq L$)

Comment: I don't really get your point. Do you want to make an answer? Would be great!

Comment: Honestly I think the ingredients of the proof are too elementary and standard for an answer to be useful to other people. If you want more help you need to tell more about what you know and don't know. Do you know about lower central series and direct sum of Lie algebras ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a concrete example with matrices.

Take the Lie algebra of all strictly upper triangular infinite matrices $M=(m_{ij})_{i,j \in \mathbf{Z}_{>0}}$ with rows and columns indexed by the positive integers and with only finitely many non-zero entries $m_{ij}$ in some ring (thanks to the finiteness condition, you can multiply these as usual, and hence the commutator is well-defined). This is not nilpotent (its central series may be described in the same way as for finite strictly upper triangular matrices!), but evidently each element is nilpotent and hence ad-nilpotent.

The philosophy that local nilpotent implies global nilpotence fails here just because local and global are so far apart for big Lie algebras.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One question: You say its central series may be discribed the same way as for the finite case, but the finite case for the strictly upper triangular matrices is nilpotent. So why is your example not nilpotent?

Comment: @user114179 The $i$th term of the central series in both cases consists of those (strictly upper triangular) matrices with the first $i$ diagonals above the main diagonal zero. For finite matrices this is eventually zero, but not for infinite matrices.