# Lie's Theorem on solvable Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a solvable, non zero subalgebra of $gl(V)$, with $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{F}$ of characteristic zero. Then $V$ contains a common eigenvector for all the endomorphisms in $\mathfrak{g}$.

Fulton and Humphreys states this theorem. Proof works on the key idea that $V$ is of  finite dimension, mainly on mathematical induction.

My doubt is can we extend this result to infinite dimensional vector spaces ? Then how will the proof works ? If not possible does there exist a counter example ?

We already know that another well known theorem on nilpotent (Engel's Theorem) does not hold in the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: As you say, we already know that it does not hold in the infinite-dimensional case, for Engel. What was your counterexample?

Comment: Counter example for Lie algebras  is from stackexchange Let  $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra of all strictly upper triangular infinite matrices, $M=\left( m_{ij}\right)_{i,j \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}}$ with finitely many non zero entries. Each element of $\mathfrak{g}$ is nilpotent and hence ad nilpotent. But $\mathfrak{g}$ is not nilpotent. The $i$th term of the central series in both cases consists of those (strictly upper triangular) matrices with the first $i$ diagonals above the main diagonal zero. For finite matrices this is eventually zero, but not for infinite matrices.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2244094/102514

Answer (score 1):

Take your vector space  over $\mathbb{C}$ to be $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Consider the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{C}[x]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}[x]$ that sends $P(x)$ to $xP(x)$. Take your subalgebra ${g}$ to be the lie subalgebra generated by $T$. $g$ is 1 dimensional (abelian), so solvable. However, $g$ does not have any common eigenvector because $T$ itself has no eigenvectors.

The thing is the fact "any endomorphism of a finite dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field must have an eigenvector" does not hold in infinite dimensions. Let alone Lie's theorem.